# Как интегрировать инлайн кнопки в телеграмм канал (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Не могу додуматься как я могу к посту в телеграм канале прикрепить инлайн кнопки, опыт в разработке ботов есть, но это не помогает)
Возможно ли это сделать не через конструктор ботов, а на python с использованием библиотеки aiogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё довольно просто. Для начала добавьте бота в администраторы канала. Затем добавьте в код вашего бота:

```py
bot.edit_message_reply_markup(channel_id, message_id, reply_markup=board)
```

Здесь `channel_id` — ID канала, который можно получить при помощи [специальных ботов](https://t.me/username_to_id_bot), `message_id` — ID сообщения, который можно получить из ссылки на пост канала или, опять же, с помощью [специальных ботов](https://t.me/MessageIDbot), а `board` — клавиатура типа `InlineKeyboardMarkup`.

Также вы можете отправить в канал новый пост с клавиатурой:

```py
bot.send_message(channel_id, text, reply_markup=board)
```

Здесь `text` — текст поста. Всё остальное по аналогии выше.

Comment: Госпади спасибо тебе добрый человек!